# Traversing through Javascript Object searching for key values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get a some specific data coming back from jquery ajax call and the **data object array looks like this**:

```
Object {Version: Object, Content: null, StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: "OK", Headers: Array[1]…}
```

The specific parts that I am interested in are

```
Headers --> Object -->Key "FORCE_REDIRECT"    ( FORCE_REDIRECT I wish to find and test if it exists)
```

Then I want to use

```
Value --> 0 -->  "Grid.html"      (Grid.html is where i plan to redirect to)
```

chrome dev tool console, this is what the array looks like

[image]

```
 console.log(data);  // shows me the array
 console.log(data.Key);   //undefined
 console.log(data[0].Key);  // blows up
```

Comment: You missed the `Headers` property. Try `console.log(data.Headers[0].Key);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's proceed with a bit more caution, so your code **can't** blow up.

First you can filter the `Headers` array to contain *only* objects with the right key:

```
if(!data.Headers){
    //fail
    return;
}
var headers = data.Headers.filter(function(o){return o.Key && o.Key==="FORCE_REDIRECT";});
```

Take the first one:

```
var headerObj = headers[0];
```

ensure it isn't null:

```
if(headerObj) //if it exists...
{
    var aValue = headerObj.Value[0]; //take the first value
    if(aValue) //if it exists...
    {
        doSomethingWith(aValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed a property (`Headers`) when trying to access your `data` object:

```
console.log(data);
console.log(data.Headers[0].Key); //"FORCE_REDIRECT"
console.log(data.Headers[0].Value[0]); //"Grid.html"
```